# How to use HOG for object detection without using SVM?

Tags: svm, hog

I am following the tutorial to calculate the HOG feature matrix. However, it does not tell how to find the object using the HOG matrix.

For example, I have an image of several pipes stacked together. I have a template image of one pipe. I want to find out the total number of pipes in the original image. I don't have training images to train the SVM. I have just one template image. Using the HOG of the template image I want to find the total number of pipes in the original image. Can it be done?

I want to know if it be done without using SVM and true positive images without having to train the SVM model.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute the distance (cosine distance for instance) between the descriptors in both images in order to match them.

So for instance, compute the HOG descriptor of a pipe and try to match it with every cells in the other image. You need a threshold too to decide if two descriptors are matched or not.

However HOG descriptors are not rotation invariant so you probably need descriptors for different orientations of one pipe.

Comment: how to do this step -->   match it with every cells in the other image